# inserting nulls much slower than empty strings, when using pyspark to write dataframe to sql server with jdbc

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on databricks/spark (1.6.2, Python) to import a dataframe to the MS SQL Server (2014) as a table. The dataframe consists around 100 million rows and 20 cols, and half of the cols are strings. More specifically, 2 cols of them are NVARCHAR's, the rests are VARCHAR's.

The performance of writing to SQL Server is difficult to reason with respect to the solution of empty strings. The writing takes 10 minutes or so to complete if empty strings are kept "as is", however, the writing time will be much longer (>10 hours) **after** the empty strings are converted to nulls. By "after", I mean that the conversion procedure is fast and beyond the scope.

The code to generate dataframe is,

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
               .options(header='false', inferSchma=None, delimiter='\t', quote='\0', 
                        treatEmptyValuesAsNulls='true') # covert if true
               .load(csvfile, schema=schema)
df.write.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "tableOfMSSQL")
```

The table in the SQL server had consistent schema with the dataframe, and **no foreign keys were set up**. I'm not sure what causes the huge difference.

Here are some hypotheses:

1. JDBC treats empty strings and nulls in totally different ways with respect to inserting. **(no evidence)**
2. The dataframe is UTF-8 encoded, while SQL Server's NVARCHAR is UTF-16LE encoded. It might be much more expensive to insert nulls than empty strings to NVARCHAR cols. **(evidence: tested on a subset of data whose NVARCHAR col is all special values, it takes much longer time to insert nulls rather than empty strings)**

Are these hypotheses reasonable? And What is the solution if so?

Comment: JDBC is just a collection of interfaces, it has - except some default methods in Java 8+, and some supporting classes - no own implementation. Behavior can be very driver (or even driver version) specific. I think this question borders on too broad, because you haven't identified if the problem is actually with the JDBC driver (eg have you eliminated the possibility that the overhead is in **how** spark uses JDBC instead), and it might not be answerable without a lot of in-depth knowledge and investigation (trial and error).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks, so do you suggest that I need to first better understand the implementation details about this specific JDBC?

Comment: If you want to know where to lay blame, you'd probably need to use the JDBC driver directly without having spark as an intermediary.